# Why would a device disconnect every time you use the camera in Android Studio & Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I've been working on a program in Flutter that opens up a camera, takes a picture, and then uses the picture in the app.  I've been connecting my Android tablet through USB tethering to Android Studio to test/run the program.  I was able to take the picture with no problems until I started trying to do stuff with the picture, like add it to the app.

As soon as the picture is taken, Android Studio returns "Lost connection to device".  It then won't do anything else in the program.  According to the Device Selector on the top left of Android Studio, the device is still connected.

I tried running the program multiple times, but it repeats the same issue each time.  I also tried it in an emulator, where it worked fine and did not give this issue.  I'm not sure what would cause the device to lose connection, even though it's still connected?  I'm not even sure what part of the code to check.

Comment: you are using [image_picker] ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ImagePicker()